# Code works in Module but not in worksheets Error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error, autofill, vba

Was hoping to recieve help on this bit of code below. It works in module 1, however does not work in any of the worksheets. I've tried my best with my limited knowledge but haven't been able to fix it.

```
Sub lastrow()
    Dim MCFPSheet As Worksheet
    Set MCFPSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MCFP Referrals YTD")

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = MCFPSheet.Range("I2").End(xlDown).Row

    With MCFPSheet.Range("R8")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("R8:R" & lastrow&)
    End With

    With MCFPSheet.Range("S2")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & lastrow&)
    End With

    With MCFPSheet.Range("T2")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & lastrow&)
    End With

    With MCFPSheet.Range("U2")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & lastrow&)
    End With

    With MCFPSheet.Range("V2")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("V2:V" & lastrow&)
    End With

    With MCFPSheet.Range("W2")
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & lastrow&)
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive

> error 1004

in `.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R8:R" & lastrow&)` line.

Comment: Because your autofill destination is missing the sheet reference.  So replace "Destination:=" with Destination:=MCFPSheet.

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

According to @Sixthsense comment that you need to specify the worksheet for your destination, also all these `With` statements don't make much sense if they are all one-liners.

It would be much shorter using the `With` that way:

```
Sub lastrow()
    Dim MCFPSheet As Worksheet
    Set MCFPSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MCFP Referrals YTD")

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = MCFPSheet.Range("I2").End(xlDown).Row

    With MCFPSheet
        .Range("R8").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R8:R" & lastrow)
        .Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("S2:S" & lastrow)
        .Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("T2:T" & lastrow)
        .Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("U2:U" & lastrow)
        .Range("V2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("V2:V" & lastrow)
        .Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("W2:W" & lastrow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that `Destination:=.Range` now also refers to the `MCFPSheet` sheet by using the leading `.` before `Range`!
And I also removed the `&` from `lastrow&` where I don't see any sense in it.